# jQuery delegate with a object selector

Tags: jquery, delegates, click

If I have a selector like $add, I can do this:

```
$add.click(function () {.....
```

But I can't do this:

```
$('body').delegate($add, 'click', function () {.....
```

How can I make it work?

**Update**

Taking @T.J. Crowder's answer in mind. This is the complete case, I create two buttons (which I insert to the dom)

```
$add      = $(document.createElement('button')).addClass('add').appendTo('body');
$subtract = $(document.createElement('button')).addClass('subtract').appendTo('body');
```

Doing delegate on $add.selector will take effect on both those buttons, why is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [the `selector` property](http://api.jquery.com/selector/). See the caveats in the docs, though, and also the notes about combining it with [`context`](http://api.jquery.com/context/). One of those caveats (not immediately obvious from the docs, though, in my view) is that when you start modifying the selection with method calls, the `selector` property becomes less useful. For instance:

```
var $add = $("div").not(".bar");
display("$add.length = " + $add.length);
// displays 3 in my example, because I have three divs that don't have class "bar"
display("$add.selector = " + $add.selector);
// displays "div.not(.bar)" (note the '.' rather than ':')
$add = $($add.selector);
display("$add.length = " + $add.length);
// displays 0 in my exmaple, because "not" is taken for a class name
```

[Live copy](http://jsbin.com/iyake4)

To my mind, that makes it not very useful.

That answers the question you actually asked, but there's probably a better way to solve the underlying design problem. :-)

---

**Update**: Re your update, the problem is probably that using `selector` on `$add` returns "button". (I haven't tried it, it just seems likely.)

I'd solve it like this:

**Option A**:

**If** you only ever have one button with the class "add", then:

```
$add      = $(document.createElement('button')).addClass('add').appendTo('body');
$subtract = $(document.createElement('button')).addClass('subtract').appendTo('body');
$('body')
    .delegate("button.add", "click", handleAdd)
    .delegate("button.subtract", "click", handleSubtract);
```

**Option B**:

If there are other buttons with those classes, give these buttons some identifying characteristic — their own class, or an `id`, or a `name`, then use that in the `delegate` selectors. Example (but adjust as necessary):

```
$add      = $("<button id='btnAdd' class='add'>").appendTo('body');
$subtract = $("<button id='btnSubtract' class='subtract'>").appendTo('body');
$('body')
    .delegate("#btnAdd", "click", handleAdd)
    .delegate("#btnSubtract", "click", handleSubtract);
```

Note there that I switched to HTML notation for creating the buttons, as it's more concise when you get into multiple attributes and such.

Side note: If there's a more precise container that isn't affected by the ajax update you can use, I would. Using `body` as the container is pretty global. You said the form is being replaced via ajax, so whatever container you're updating in your ajax all would probably be a good choice.

Comment: Ok, so thanks for a great answer. There's a problem though, se my updated question.

Comment: I'm probably just thinking wrong. I will instead explain what I'm trying to do. I'm working with a form, in that form some input fields have a class called countable. When the form is initiated I'm adding to buttons in div next to the input. The problem is that the form can be changed via ajax, therefore there needs to be a delegate. Sure I can just reattach the buttons but I'd rather do it with delegate.

Comment: @tbleckert: Updated. Basically, you just can't use the `$add` object that way, but that's okay, you really don't need to.

Comment: Yes of course I have a deeper container, body was just an example :) Thanks for your input, I will try to solve it :)